# Akka Clustering - Can actors outlive the node that created them?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I would like to be able to create an actor from one Akka node of a cluster, in a way that the actor will live on regardless of whether the node that created it is running or not.

This is the scenario I am trying to handle:

1. Node A starts.
2. Node B starts.
3. Nodes A and B form a cluster.
4. Node A creates a FooActor.
5. Node A terminates.
6. **Node B is still able to search for and find the FooActor created by Node A.**
7. **Node B kills FooActor.**

At the moment, when Node A terminates, the actors it created are lost.

Could you please let me know if this is possible for an actor to outlive the node/member that created it.

Thank you.

Comment: It is natural for FooActor to die as it exists under the realm of NodeA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is just that your actor outlive to a node termination probably the best option for you would be having no care about their physical location of that actor in the cluster and in that case scenario you can make use of two options either [Cluster Sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html) or [Cluster Singleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-singleton.html) in the case you have to have exactly one actor of that type you are mentioning.